Sync request WORKS Async NOT, SOAP Zeep, httpx and SSL cause sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)

Issue Summary:
My synchronous implementation using the Zeep library works perfectly:
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.cert = cert_path
transport = Transport(session=session, operation_timeout=60)
client = Client(
    "url.wsdl",
    transport=transport,
)
client.service.GetSomething(request)  # success

Trying to make it asynchronous:
from zeep import AsyncClient as AsyncClientZeep
from zeep.transports import AsyncTransport
import httpx

async def async_request():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(cert=cert_path) as client_httpx:
        wsdl_response = await client_httpx.get('url.wsdl')
        print(f'WSDL Status Code: {wsdl_response.status_code}')  # This part is working
        
        # Create the Zeep AsyncTransport with the httpx client
        transport = AsyncTransport(client=client_httpx, operation_timeout=60)
        
        # Initialize the Zeep client with the transport
        client = AsyncClientZeep("url.wsdl", transport=transport)
        
        response = await client.service.GetSomething(request)  # This request returns the error

# Example usage
import asyncio
asyncio.run(async_request())

The error:
ConnectError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)

Troubleshooting Steps Tried:
I attempted various approaches, including different SSL setups:
import ssl

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT')
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=ssl_context):
    # same error occurs

None of these configurations resolved the issue.
Note: Zeep currently supports httpx for async operations.

